# Verification of my solution to $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy^2+x}{x^2y+y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I'm not certain that the following solution is entirely correct:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy^2+x}{x^2y+y}=\frac{1}{y}\frac{x(2y^2+1)}{1+x^2}$$
$$\frac{y\frac{dy}{dx}}{2y^2+1}=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$
$$\frac{y}{2y^2+1}dy=\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$\int\frac{y}{y^2+1}dy=2\int\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|y^2+1\right|=\ln\left|x^2+1\right|+\mathrm{c}$$
$$y=\sqrt{2e^c(x^2+1)-1}$$

Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a mistake between eq. 3 and eq. 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a wrong turn in your 3th to your 4th equation, it should be:

$$y'(x)=\frac{2xy(x)^2+x}{x^2y(x)+y(x)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\text{d}y(x)}{\text{d}x}=\frac{2xy(x)^2+x}{x^2y(x)+y(x)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\text{d}y(x)}{\text{d}x}=\frac{x\left(\frac{1}{y(x)}+2y(x)\right)}{x^2+1}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\frac{\text{d}y(x)}{\text{d}x}}{\frac{1}{y(x)}+2y(x)}=\frac{x}{x^2+1}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{\frac{\text{d}y(x)}{\text{d}x}}{\frac{1}{y(x)}+2y(x)}\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{x}{x^2+1}\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{4}\ln(2y(x)^2+1)=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+1)+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)=\pm\frac{\sqrt{\text{C}(x^2+1)^2-1}}{\sqrt{2}}$$